# Creating the signature value of a digital signature “manually”?

Tags: soap, xml, crypto

I need to sign some xml. The issue is that I cannot use the native Salesforce Crypto.signxml() method because I need to sign the soap:body and place the signature in the soap:header element, and this isn't possible as far as I can see.

There is also no native canonicalization method, so I am "manually" creating the digest by manually altering the XML into its canonicalized form, and this works just fine.

Then I place it into a SignedInfo block and try to run a Crypto.signWithCertificate method on that block. I am using RSA-SHA1, and I receive a result, but it is not what I am expecting. I am curious is the issue I am having is on the canonicalization of that SignedInfo block.

I have this block:

```
<SignedInfo>
  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
  <Reference URI="#Body">
    <Transforms>
      <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue>AMyUbs9zGUGJ52sFMalRNFFbI5o=</DigestValue>
  </Reference>
</SignedInfo>
```

Which I canonicalize to this:

```
<SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod><Reference URI="#Body"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod><DigestValue>AMyUbs9zGUGJ52sFMalRNFFbI5o=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo>
```

Then I would call Crypto.signWithCertificate on that data with RSA-SHA1 using my key.

Is anything in my thinking incorrect?